# Get the detail of overlapping bookings mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing a stable booking system where user can book and update their room bookings and chose stables from interactive map.

My stable registration db structure is like below

```
event_detail_stable_registrations
| id | accountId | eventId | stableId | checkInDate | checkOutDate | 
  5     233         55         66       26-06-2017    28-06-2017
  6     234         55         66       28-06-2017    29-06-2017
```

When user updates the booking but do not change the `checkInDate` and `checkOutDate` then its an easy scenario which i have implemented already.

In above case if user `234` updates the booking and change `checkInDate` then the query should return `233` for `stableId 66` but my query returns '234' as `accountId`

Another scenario is when user changes the `checkInDate` and or `checkOutDate` of the registration. User A wants to change the booking detail how can i check if any overlapping for updated `checkInDate` and or `checkOutDate` for user's booking and if those are already booked then which `accountId` has booked it.

Right now I am running following query which gives me correct information about overlapping dates but could not get the information of account who has booked it.

Query always returns the user's accountId for overlapping dates as well.

```
 SET @checkInDate = '2017-04-27 14:00:00' , @checkOutDate = '2017-05-01 10:00:00' ; 

SELECT a.*,
IF(b.`stableid` IS NULL,"Avalalable","Not Available") as `status`,
IF(NOT b.`stableid` IS NULL,b.`accountId`,"") as `overLapAccount`,
IF(NOT b.`stableid` IS NULL,b.`checkInDate`,"") as `start_overlap`,
IF(NOT b.`stableid` IS NULL,b.`checkOutDate`,"") as `end_overlap`
FROM `event_detail_stable_registrations` b
LEFT JOIN `stables` a
ON a.`id` = b.`stableid` AND
 (((`checkInDate` BETWEEN @checkInDate AND @checkOutDate)
  OR (`checkOutDate` BETWEEN @checkInDate AND @checkOutDate))
   OR ((@checkInDate BETWEEN `checkInDate` AND `checkOutDate`) 
     OR (@checkOutDate BETWEEN `checkInDate` AND `checkOutDate`))
)
ORDER BY a.`name`
```

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a792/10) where I haven't used the same DB structure but its similar.

The output I get for the same `stable` booked by multiple account for given period is fine but with the query I am using, I get `null` in the column `name,stableId`.

Answer (score 0):

Part 2 of your scenario:

MariaDB-10.5 [Application Time Periods - WITHOUT OVERLAPS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/application-time-periods/#without-overlaps) can enforce the constraints of non-overlapping bookings:

```
ALTER TABLE event_detail_stable_registrations
ADD period FOR booking(checkInDate, checkOutDate),
ADD PRIMARY KEY (accountId, stableId, booking WITHOUT OVERLAPS)
```

A user cancelling a day is just:

```
DELETE
FROM event_detail_stable_registrations
FOR PORTION OF booking
FROM '2017-04-29 14:00:00' TO '2017-04-30 10:00:00'
WHERE accountId=5
  AND stableId=866
```

Which splits the non-deleted dates booking entry over periods.

Any UPDATE of a booking enforces the constraints.

ref: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=2f8d02fc29fbbc61fd5010a31570354e)