# In a table with room number, start time integer, end time integer, and person id, how to restrict time for room usage?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table for room bookings in which I have columns:

- Room_num,
- Person_id,
- start int,
- end int

I want to add a restriction/constraint in the table such that a particular room cannot be booked by multiple person_id(s) for conflicting start/end durations.

I am going in the direction of having start and end times as integers where they represent the start of an hour (1 being 1 am and 13 being 1 pm). I am not able to figure out how to add such a restriction.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: If you are storing time values, use the time datatype? And then have a go at adding the constraint and show us how far you got and where you are stuck.

Comment: Why is "time" stored as an integer? At the sound of the chime, it will be 2 billion o'clock? If it stores the hour of a day - when it needs to be just large enough for a maximum value of 23 and always greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: If you are using MariaDB, [Application Time periods without overlaps](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/application-time-periods/#without-overlaps) solves your problem like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366523/get-the-detail-of-overlapping-bookings-mysql/68264037#68264037). Using native DATE/TIME times is always recommended over kludging it with an inter.

Comment: Are your end times inclusive or exclusive. For a one hour meeting that starts at 1pm (start = 13) is the end time 13 (inclusive) or 14 (exclusive). Also, do you need to consider late night cases - 10pm to midnight or 10pm to 2am? I would recommend including the date using a DATETIME type and exclusive end date/times.

Comment: So far i have added a constraint that lets the max int value be 23 for 11 pm. I don't need to consider late night cases like that. Also, meetings are 1 hr at the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a check against the table before inserting the data. additionally, as @DaleK mentioned, it is better to go with time datatype, as you can leverage time functions.

```sql
if not exists (SELECT * FROM Table where room_num = @room_num and end_time > @start_time and start_time < @end_time)
BEGIN

     INSERT INTO Table(personid, room_num, start_time, end_time)
     values(@personid, @room_num, @start_time, @end_time)

END
ELSE
BEGIN
   throw 51000, 'You are already having room booking conflicting with current booking', 1;
END
```

Comment: The overlap test appears to be missing a condition. Suggest `where ... and end_time > @start_time and start_time < @end_time`. The comparison operators (> vs >= and < vs <=) also depend on whether the end times are exclusive or inclusive.

Comment: ... And also suggest dropping the `personid = @personid` condition. Ohtherwise this only prevents the same person from overbooking.

Comment: @TN, Thanks for your extra check on this. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely understand it now. I hadn't considered starting out with an if condition like that and was only thinking of a way to add it as a constraint.

Comment: @user3489850, if it answers your question, please mark it as answer. It will be helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you always book whole hours you can just indicate the start. If someone wants 2 hours they book 2 slots. We then use Room Number + Date + Hour as primary key which automatically blocks all duplicate bookings.
This could be modified to use smaller block, half-hour, 10 minutes etc. by modifying the datatype or slotHour.

> ```
> create table bookings (
>   Room_num int not null,
>   Person_id int not null,
>   slotDate date not null,
>   slotHour int not null,
>   constraint pk_slot primary key (Room_num,slotDate, slotHour)
>   );
> ```

> ```
> insert into bookings values (1, 1,'2022-02-25',10);
> insert into bookings values (2, 1,'2022-02-25',10);
> insert into bookings values (1, 1,'2022-02-25',11);
> ```

> ```
> select * from bookings;
> ```

> ```
> room_num | person_id | slotdate   | slothour
> -------: | --------: | :--------- | -------:
>        1 |         1 | 2022-02-25 |       10
>        2 |         1 | 2022-02-25 |       10
>        1 |         1 | 2022-02-25 |       11
> ```

> ```
> insert into bookings values (1, 1,'2022-02-25',10);
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_slot"
> ```

DETAIL:  Key (room_num, slotdate, slothour)=(1, 2022-02-25, 10) already exists.

> 

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fda778d91808e692a038addc1a31e569)*